# Additive Merging JSON doc via php

Tags: javascript, php, json, mongodb

I am working on a web app that aggregates json data from a date range query using PHP/ Mongodb. Each date returns a similarly structured json document whose data I want to aggregate to produce a final 'totals' json doc. Unfortunately, the data is too big to simply encode into the web page and merge in javascript which means I need to do an additive merge of the data in php. Anyone have a clean solution for this problem?

doc 1.

```
    {
      'field': {
                 a: 3,
                 b: 
                    { 
                      c: 1
                    }
               },
      'field2': 2
    }
```

doc 2

```
    {
      'field': {
                 a: 5,
                 b: 
                    { 
                      c: 6
                    }
               }
    }
```

result:

```
   {
      'field': {
                 a: 8,
                 b: 
                    { 
                      c: 7
                    }
               },
       'field2': 2
    }
```

Comment: Stuff like this should be done on the server rather than the client anyway.

Comment: Are all these documents coming from the same collection? If so, you should be able to use MongoDB's [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to calculate the sums.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need to learn how to use the aggregation framework to add up jsons fields without having to specify the json structure ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wrote this additive json merge function based on other answers I found on here. It takes the two results from Mongo and adds them together if possible.

```
function json_merge_additive( $arr1, $arr2 )
{
    $keys = array_keys( $arr2 );
    foreach( $keys as $key ) {
        if( isset($arr1[$key]) && is_array($arr1[$key]) && is_array($arr2[$key]) 
        ) 
        {
            $arr1[$key] = json_merge_additive( $arr1[$key], $arr2[$key] );
        } 
        else if(isset( $arr1[$key]) && $arr2[$key] && is_numeric($arr1[$key]) && is_numeric($arr2[$key]) )
        {
            $arr1[$key] += $arr2[$key];
        }
        else // add key 2 to 1. 
        {
            $arr1[$key] = $arr2[$key];
        }
    }
    return $arr1;
}
```